Espressione fiorentina settecentesca
Buongiorno a tutti,
nella commedia settecentesca Il marito alla moda
di Giovanni Battista Fagiuoli ho trovato la seguente espressione:

Ans. E che di’ tu? che tu se’ sguajato? lo dico anch’io; ecco il secondo bel detto, spiritoso certo, c’è del sale dimolto. Del resto le cose non vanno male affatto, è vero?
Ciap. Eh le vanno taía taía; c’enno sempre de’ passeggieri: il posto è buono.

Cosa potrebbe voler dire "taìa taìa"? Potrebbe essere una storpiatura, essendo Ciapo contadino solito a deformare le parole; i vocabolari consultati purtroppo non mi hanno aiutata: qualcuno saprebbe darmi qualche suggerimento?
Grazie mille,
Sabina Ghirardi

Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @SabinaGhirardi! Purtroppo, l'unico riferimento a questa espressione che sono riuscita a trovare è nella tua tesi di dottorato. Quindi l'espressione taía taía sarebbe stata sottolineata da Manzoni nella sua copia della commedia di Fagiuoli?

Grazie mille!
Esatto, è un’espressione sottolineata da Manzoni nella commedia di Fagiuoli, che la usa anche in altre commedie: sembrerebbe una forma di intercalare di cui però non riesco a rintracciare il significato preciso.

@user10185: Qui puoi chiedere di unificare i tuoi account.
